# Widgets (home screen apps) using sencha touch 2?

Tags: widget, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to create home screen app like widgets using sencha touch? (like the weather widget which stays on our mobile home screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Touch web apps should sit in a Web View regardless of where that is, so in theory that could be feasible.
Unfortunately Web Views are not supported in App Widgets https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html so there is no way obtaining that on Android at this time.

iOS is not going to support anything like widgets until iOS8.